# How am I supposed to integrate Chartboost sdk in my libgdx android game

Tags: java, android, libgdx, chartboost

So this site https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201219545-Android-Integration has a guide how to integrate the chartboost sdk, but it looks like it is meaned for android apps, since they are talking about activities. I have no idea how to do this. The only thing I could do so far is adding the chartboost.jar file into my android/libs file. How am I supposed to continue?

Comment: Have you even tried to find answer in google? After typing **Chartboost libgdx** at least two good looking pages are on the top - try to find out and then create new question saying what you've tried so far

Comment: @m.antkowicz I tried the first link, but I'm already getting stuck since nobody clearly explains where I should put my chartboost dependency. I tried to put it everywhere, but still AndroidStudio can't find it

Comment: It's funny that now this question is number 5 on google search "Chartboost libgdx"? haha. now where can i get some info about this?

Comment: did this work for you: https://gist.github.com/burakkurkcu/6f2b5a54e2df9d90fffa